# With a negative translateY on child, how to adjust parent height accordingly?

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a website with a header that I slide up on first scroll using translateY(-590px). The problem I get is that all the way on the bottom of my page, I get an extra bit of white space on some browsers.

A demo of the problem in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1shxwmv8/3/)

Here's the example code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div>block 1</div>
    <div>block 2</div>
    <div>block 3</div>
    <div>block 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
    background-color: grey;
}
.content div{
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}
.content.scrolled div:last-child{
    height: 100px; 
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".content").addClass("scrolled");
    }, 700);
});
```

How can I make it so that the parent automatically adjusts its height.

ps
I use translateY because I have an animation on the sliding and using margin-top would be slow on Safari (because redrawing everything constantly). This is why I have to use translate instead of margin.

Comment: This gets pretty close, but It's not perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/1shxwmv8/5/

Comment: it does though it is kind of hacky and not applicable on the project

Comment: What is the purpose of this? I need to know so I know what an appropriate solution is - for example, are you able to display none or visibility:hide the element that is "translated" (since it is already being hidden) - then you would just take the sum of the heights of the visible elements - I am working on a Fiddle for you if you can give me some more information.

Comment: The purpose is to create an image header that slides to a smaller version which is then a fixed menubar on top. The content below the header also slides up with the same speed as the header gets smaller. I'll add some screenshots next monday. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the height of the resulting header is fixed, then you can just add a height value to .content.scrolled like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/1shxwmv8/8/

```
.content.scrolled {
    height: 300px;
}
```

Hope I understood your question and helped.

Comment: I could do that, but I don't know the height of the content. I'll add some screenshots Monday morning to clarify the question. :)